# Loop Inside inside A Variable

Tags: php

I need a variable that has a loop inside it

Like

```
$data=foreach ($array as $data ) {'$_POST[$namee]',}
```

If It is not possible

Please Tell Me Alternative

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. What is a "variable with a loop inside it"? An array? And what do you mean by "I need"? What do you have to do with it?

Comment: You need a function signature basically. Wrap that loop inside a function and assign it to a variable. Or maybe you want to use array_map

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve with this code exactly? Maybe give us some examples too. Then it will be easier to help. Right now what you are asking does not make much sense, but it may become clearer if you give some more details. We would like to help, but it is hard for us to understand.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it and it's possible

also it's easy

at first you need 3 function

```
//RETURNS BEFORE, AFTER, AND BETWEEN FOR STRINGS
    function before($thisis, $inthat) {
        return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $thisis));
    }

    function after($thisis, $inthat) {
        if(!is_bool(strpos($inthat, $thisis))) {
            return substr($inthat, strpos($inthat,$thisis)+strlen($thisis));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function between($thisis, $that, $inthat) {
        return before($that, after($thisis, $inthat));
    }//END before(), after(), and between() functions
```

after that you need template, (template is your variable you will put foreach in there)

```
    $template='
    <Mehrdad_Array_Row>
    <Mehrdad_Num>
    <Mehrdad_Data>
    </Mehrdad_Array_Row>
    ';
```

you need do foreach for your template

```
$array=array(['mehrdad'],['dashti']);
$insert = "";
$mehrdad = between("<Mehrdad_Array_Row>", "</Mehrdad_Array_Row>", $template);
$num = 0;
foreach ($array as $data ) {
$num++;
$insert .= $mehrdad;
$insert = str_replace("<Mehrdad_Num>", "$num", $insert);
$insert = str_replace("<Mehrdad_Data>", "$data[0]", $insert);
}
$template = str_replace("<Mehrdad_Array_Row>".$mehrdad."</Mehrdad_Array_Row>", $insert, $template);
if (@!$insert){$template = str_replace("<Mehrdad_Array_Row>". $mehrdad."</Mehrdad_Array_Row>", "", $template);}
```

at the end

```
<?=$template?>
```

i hope i could to help you